# log4j xml config in spring 5.2.8

Tags: spring, log4j, log4j2

I am getting the following warning in spring mvc 5.2.8 when I configure log4j xml. The log messages are not printed in the console window.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mchange.v2.log.MLog).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have added the following to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

log4j2.xml in src folder

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="log_console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="Log:%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n %L"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
</configuration>
```

web.xml

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Has someone faced this before? Can someone guide me how to solve this error?

Comment: Trying a Log4J config class with Log4j2 is obviously not going to work. What do you want to use Log4j or log4j2? Currently your dependencies and config is a mess.

Comment: I want to use log4j

Comment: Then don't use log4j2 dependencies or log4j2 configuration (although I would suggest using Log4j2 as that is the new version of log4j).